# twilio upload file in assets for manipulation

Tags: function, twilio

I am trying to record multiple voicemail and append them in real time.For latency purpose ,planing to host the function in twilio function . I want to upload recording  file in asset from function,for cutting file.Is there any way to send recording file to asset from function  ?

I know how to retrieve mp3 uri of recording on call